# String to typescript class name

Tags: javascript, angular, string, typescript

I am Generating a typescript code dynamically. So i have this:

```
let data = {
  path: 'home',
  component: '${homeComponentName}',
  children:[]
};

let homeComponentName = 'HomeComponent'
let tpl= eval('`' + JSON.stringify(data) + '`')
```

Now my result is:

```
{
  path: 'home',
  component: 'HomeComponent',
  children:[]
},
```

But i need to remove the quotes in 'HomeComponent'. The expected results is:

```
{
  path: 'home',
  component: HomeComponent,
  children:[]
},
```

Comment: Json will not be valid if you do this

Comment: This is intended to be used in typescript on angular 6 app. HomeComponent is a component instance

Comment: the hell you did to parse the data? Why don't just use `JSON.parse(...)`?

Comment: It is a weird requirement but try using string replace function to remove quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you trying to do is not possible, because not only you need to update its value but you need to import the path of that component at the top as well,

Comment: This will result in 'HomeComponent'. As i said, i want to remove the single quotes in 'HomeComponent' - > HomeComponent, which is a angular component instance.

Comment: Hey, I am sorry my bad, Editing my answer  it's not possible, Removing the quotes won't help as you need to import the component(its path) at the top to compile it as well.